# unable to zoom on double tap on uiwebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, zooming

I needed to enable zoom in and zoom out in webview using gestures. So for that I enabled the scalesPageTofit property. But after doing so my content that I am displaying in the webview becomes so small in size that it fits in one corner of the webview instead of taking up the entire screen and I think its right because by doing so the webpage is scaled to fit the screen. So to resolve the issue I added a line in my html file that I am basically uploading in my webview.

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = 480, initial-scale = 1.0 user-scalable = yes">
```

Now the webview fits the complete screen and I can zoom in and zoom out by expanding the view. The problem is that I am unable to zoom in using double tap but can definately zoom out. One thing more the size of my html is 320*480 itself. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Laura

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue? I am facing similar..

Comment: you need to try to use user-scalable = no

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a comma before `user-scalable`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change viewport content width to 320px?
Or just try double tap on landscape orientation